# Getting error when copying custom image from one region to another in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli

I am working on copying a `Custom Image` from `norteurope` region to `eastus` in `Azure`, so I can create `Virtual Machines` in `eastus` region based on the copied `Custom Image`. I am using following `Azure CLI` command:

```
az image copy `
--source-object-name "playground-windows-vm-image-1" `
--source-resource-group 'playground-demo-rg' `
--target-location 'eastus' `
--target-resource-group 'layground-demo-rg2' `
--cleanup
```

The `Azure CLI` copy command is throwing an error and giving me following error message:

[image]

I am using `Azure CLI` and mainly  did following steps:

1. I created a new `Resource Group` with name `playground-demo-rg2` in `eastus`
2. Installed `Image Copy Extension` in order to copy from `northeurope` to `eastus`
3. Copying an existing `Custom Image(playground-windows-vm-image-1)` from `Source Resource Group(playground-demo-rg)` to `Target Resource Group(playground-demo-rg2)`

I have uploaded the full `PS` script which threw the above error upon execution:

https://github.com/jagjitsingh700/AzureVirtualMachines/blob/master/CopyingCustomImageToRegion.ps1

Comment: Could you please provide me the detailed error message?

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/issues/318) and I also face this error. A new open issue is Github [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/issues/993).

As a workaround, you could use [Shared Image Gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/shared-image-galleries) in Azure. Using a Shared Image Gallery you can share your images to different users, service principals, or AD groups within your organization. Shared images can be replicated to multiple regions, for quicker scaling of your deployments.

Or [copy Managed Images with Powershell](https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/copy-managed-images/). Additionally, you could refer to [this blog](https://www.obungi.com/2017/07/21/how-to-copy-an-azure-vm-from-region-a-to-region-b/) to Copy an Azure VM From Region A to Region B.